# Refresh Single View Controller in Container View

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I need help refreshing a single view controller in a container view by passing a variable value to it. I have a storyboard which contains a view controller with a container view. See the following image:

[image: Container View]

**Total Sales by Company Users** is changing by picker view controller, means it will refresh my view controller for different data.

Now, I'm adding my view controller in this container view of `DashbordVC` programatically by using following code:

```
var previousViewController : UIViewController?
var selectedIndex : Int = 0

// TopSalesVC - Instantiate ViewController
private lazy var topSalesVC: TopSalesVC = {
    var vc = TopSalesVC.viewController()
    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    return vc
}()    

// Methods
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupView()
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

func setupView() {

    self.previousViewController = self.topSalesVC
    self.add(asChildViewController: self.topSalesVC)
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

    self.addChildViewController(viewController)
    self.containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)

    viewController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
    viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

This code works for when the view loads, but when I change for picker view controller row and click on the Done button, it's does nothing.

Now my code for picker view `didSelect` row as follows:

```
override func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    self.selectedIndex = row
}
```

I have the Done button in the toolbar of picker view. So when I click on it, it executes the following code:

```
@IBAction func btnDoneClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    BaseVC.isPickerOpen = false

    self.showPicker(false) { (success) in

        if self.previousViewController != nil {
            self.remove(asChildViewController: self.previousViewController!)
        }

        switch self.selectedIndex {

        case 0:
            .....
            .....
            break

        case 1:
            .....
            .....
            break

        case 2:
            .....
            .....
            break

        case 3:
            .....
            .....
            break

        case 4:
            self.topSalesVC.salesBy = .invoiceByCustomer
            self.previousViewController = self.topSalesVC
            self.add(asChildViewController: self.topSalesVC)
            break

        case 5:
            self.topSalesVC.salesBy = .invoiceByUser
            self.previousViewController = self.topSalesVC
            self.add(asChildViewController: self.topSalesVC)
            break

        case 6:
            self.topSalesVC.salesBy = .supplier
            self.previousViewController = self.topSalesVC
            self.add(asChildViewController: self.topSalesVC)
            break

        case 7:
            self.topSalesVC.salesBy = .manufacturer
            self.previousViewController = self.topSalesVC
            self.add(asChildViewController: self.topSalesVC)
            break

        case 8:
            self.topSalesVC.salesBy = .masterProduct
            self.previousViewController = self.topSalesVC
            self.add(asChildViewController: self.topSalesVC)
            break

        case 9:
            self.topSalesVC.salesBy = .user
            self.previousViewController = self.topSalesVC
            self.add(asChildViewController: self.topSalesVC)
            break

        case 10:
            self.topSalesVC.salesBy = .customer
            self.previousViewController = self.topSalesVC
            self.add(asChildViewController: self.topSalesVC)
            break

        case 11:
            self.topSalesVC.salesBy = .customerTag
            self.previousViewController = self.topSalesVC
            self.add(asChildViewController: self.topSalesVC)
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

With the above method, from cases 4 to 11 which are using the same view controller, just changes its variable value and adds it to container view.

So my issue is that when I change the picker view value to refresh data for a single view controller, it has no effect on my view controller. Displays the same data and initial state.

I have checked TopSalesVC and there the code is working absolutely fine. So there is no issue with TopSalesVC's Code.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Place a breakpoint and check if your `childViewController's` `viewDidLoad` is getting called or not.

Comment: @iPeter, I have checked this, `viewDidLoad` not called.

Comment: Then your `refresh` will not work right? Try with `removeFromParent` before adding it again as a childViewController.

Comment: @iPeter, I'm already doing this in my remove method, which is already posted in my question.

Comment: Is `willAppear` getting called?

Comment: @iPeter, Yes it is called, I got it. thanks. you can post descriptive answer so it will be helpful to other also. Thanks you so much, You saved my day.

Comment: View will appear is the answer

Comment: @SagarChauhan You have too much repeated code. Create function   and pass argument as `salesBy` and call it for every case for switch

Comment: Improvement 2: Create salesBy Enum property instead of  selectedIndex. and create case for every enum cases like masterProduct, users etc. This is more readable code

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, I can do that, but there are also some different view controller. so it's not consistence.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, Thanks for better solution, But, I have already updated my code to remove redundant code, I got it when I posting my questions. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling the refresh method of your childViewController from `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad` as `viewDidLoad` will not be called when adding it as `childViewController`.

Hope this helps.